# why am I able to delete/list objects in a S3 Bucket without permission

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I´m wondering why I´m able to list or even delete objects from a `s3` bucket although public access is blocked and just the bucket-owner has list/write access to the bucket.
[image]

[image]

This is what I´m doing in code:

```
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
        {
          
            ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                MaxKeys = 10
            };
            ListObjectsV2Response response;
            do
            {
                response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

                foreach (Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object obj in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);                        
                }
                
                request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;

            } while (response.IsTruncated);              

            DeleteObjectResponse resp = await s3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(new Amazon.S3.Model.DeleteObjectRequest() { BucketName = bucketName, Key = "dummykey" });
```

Any idea what I´m doing wrong? Shouldn´t the acl block me from even listing any contents?

Comment: Does your connection string include credentials?

Comment: As the docs say for that constructor - _"Constructs AmazonS3Client with the credentials loaded from the application's default configuration, and if unsuccessful from the Instance Profile service on an EC2 instance."_

Comment: I´m not using any credentials when I´m creating the amazons3client-object.

Comment: @stuartd: Does that mean that the credentials are used from the AWS-Explorer that´s installed in Visual Studio?

Comment: @harryh100 I couldn't say. But if you're accessing objects, it seems almost certain it's getting them from _somewhere_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your code that use AWS SDK recovers credentials (**a pair of AWS Access KEY ID/AWS Secret Key**) related to the bucket owner.

If you can, take a look at the IAM user corresponding to the bucket owner, to see if he has **programmatic access**.

On which is the code running? You should look at the different possibilities to store AWS credentials:

- Environement variables
- `~/.aws/credentials` file
- ...

For more information, look at **Configuration settings and precedence**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence

**Bonus**: Please find the good pratcices to manage your access keys:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems like it´s using the credentials files in /.aws.